# How to install Overmind in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

First of all, I am a newbie in Linux, now that is out of the way: I am experiencing issues with [Overmind](https://github.com/DarthSim/overmind) installation.

After downloading the binary file I tried with the trinity of installations, but for it did not work, no configuration, the read me is the same as the one in GitHub which is next to no help for me. Attempted with package installers, but they don't recognize the binary files as such.

Extracted the contents and tried all kinds of stuff I read online but to no avail. I am sure I am missing something really simple, but apparently I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the .gz and .sha256 files from the official releases  [from official github repo](https://github.com/DarthSim/overmind/releases) (latest release normally)

Either use web ui and right-click these two files or download directly

```
cd ~/Download
mkdir overmind && cd overmind
wget https://github.com/DarthSim/overmind/releases/download/v2.2.2/overmind-v2.2.2-linux-amd64.gz
wget https://github.com/DarthSim/overmind/releases/download/v2.2.2/overmind-v2.2.2-linux-amd64.gz.sha256sum
```

now make sure the sha256 checks out

```
shasum -a 256 overmind-v2.2.2-linux-amd64.gz | awk '{print $1}' && cat overmind-v2.2.2-linux-amd64.gz.sha256sum
```

You should see two long hash strings, they should match identically.  If so proceed, if not, don't.

```
# unzip the binary
gunzip -d overmind-v2.2.2-linux-amd64.gz

# make it executable
sudo chmod +x overmind-v2.2.2-linux-amd64

# move to an appropriate binary path
sudo mv overmind-v2.2.2-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/

# symlink it for easier use
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/overmind-v2.2.2-linux-amd64 /usr/bin/overmind

# restart your terminal session

# now you can run it from anywhere by just running
overmind start
```

Comment: Note: In the `sudo mv overmind-v2.2.2-linux-amd64.gz /usr/local/bin/` command the `.gz` is incorrect. It should be removed. Thanks.

Comment: Also I had to change permissions on the file i.e `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/overmind-v2.2.2-linux-amd64` for the `overmind start` to work.

Comment: @JigneshGohel updated both as per your comments thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To save some time for newbies like me:

1. Download the binary for your version
2. mkdir ~/bin/
3. move the extracted binary from your downloads to ~/bin/
   3.1 EXTRACTED
4. chmod +x ~/bin/overmind
5. export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

With that set-up, any scripts you drop into ~/bin will be executed when you type their name in the terminal.

Comment: good answer but you need 2 things to make it better